# efficient way of performing a discrete voronoi tessellation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting, voronoi

Suppose that I have a small number of points in d-dimensional space, c_1, c_2, ..., c_N where N is around 50-100.

Now, I have a set of samples x_1, x_2, ..., x_M in d-dimensional space where M can be as large as 1e7.

Is there an efficient way to segregate the samples x_1, x_2, ..., x_M such that for each j, we assign x_j to the point c_k for which the euclidean distance from x_j to c_k (for all k) is the smallest?

So far, I am employing a brute force approach: for every j, I would just calculate the distance of x_j from all c_k's. In low dimensions, I can easily do this using repmat in Matlab and some vectorized code.

However, in high dimensions, I run into the problem of memory when doing repmat especially if M is very large. As a consequence, running a for loop to iterate over every x_j becomes very slow. Since I have to do this clustering procedure a number of times, my whole simulation takes longer than a day.

Any ideas on how to make the clustering process more efficient? I tried looking around but only found k-means clustering which is not relevant to me since c_1,...,c_N are given.

Comment: Look at using [kd-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).  See for example [this](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~hartley/Papers/PDF/SilpaAnan:CVPR08.pdf).  The precise details probably depend on the details of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearest neighbor structures like k-d trees work very poorly in high dimensions (curse of dimensionality). My first suggestion would be to process the samples in chunks that are large enough to avoid the overhead of the MATLAB interpreter but small enough that they fit comfortably in cache.

Comment: Thanks for this comment! Yes, I was thinking of breaking it in chunks. It seems that you're suggesting that it's more worthwhile than trying out kd trees first.